# Spec for Ubuntu latest version

Tags: system-installation

My lap has the spec of 1.90GHz I3 4030U Intelcor  but advised is 2.0 dual-core.
can my lap install Ubuntu latest version and work normaly in same fast?
I want it for studio purpose like design, graphics, editing, photograph etc..

Answer (score 0):

For 2.0 GHz Dual-Core processor, let us consider:

**Intel® Pentium® Processor E2180**

According to [CPUBenchMark](http://cpubenchmark.net), the scores for

1. Intel® Pentium® Processor E2180 is [1086](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Pentium%20E2180%20@%202.00GHz).
2. Intel® I3® Processor 4030U is [2684](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i3-4030U%20@%201.90GHz).

Now, these results here are NOT absolute and for reference only because the hardware varies for each individual.

But the point is, Ubuntu takes into consideration the minimum of the specified processor and publishes the requirement on their website. So, accordingly your hardware is OK for an Ubuntu installation. But if you are conscious, you can use a minimal DE such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Also, the softwares you are requesting WILL run in your machine but the performance cannot be guaranteed as it may also vary for each individual.